# matplotlib: enlarge axis-scale label

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to enlarge the axis-scale label in matplotlib (circled in red in the enlarged plot below)?

[image]

I've used `ax.tick_params()` to successfully edit the tick labels, but I haven't been able to find anything about this specific piece of the plot.

Worse comes to worst, I could go with a manual `text()` insertion, but I'd like something more direct if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a line like this

`ax.xaxis.get_children()[1].set_size(15)`

To change your major tick scale label (I guess we can call it so) to 15 points, if you plot the plot on `ax`.

If you plot using the `pyplot` API, add a line of `ax=plt.gca()` as well.

Comment: This appears only to affect the tick labels, and not the scale-label I've shown in the image. Basically has the same behavior as a call to `ax.tick_params()`.

Comment: Nono, I delete that one, see the new edit. Sorry, `xaxis`, I will change that too

Comment: Perfect! I'm curious where you found such info, as I've actually been searching for a solution for some time now. Some documentation I failed to read?

Comment: When suspect some functionality is not documented, I'd get the `get_children()` of the primary suspect, in this case `xaxis`. In this case it is simple. There are only two `text` objects, the first one `get_children()[0]` has to be axis label. Then we know we want the second one.